# Getting Error: Districtna.getExtent(...) is null

Tags: geometry, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I have dojo combo box to display district names when I select one district it should zoom to that particular `district.selection` is working fine but zooming not happening I am getting `Districtna.getExtent().expand(2)` is null.

Can any one tell me why I am not getting geometry of selected district.

Below the  code I am using to zoom the selected district :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
<head> 
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"/>
  <title></title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.16/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">    
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.16/esri/css/esri.css">
  <style> 
    html, body, #map {
      padding:0;
      margin:0;
      height:100%;
    }
    #HomeButton {
      position: absolute;
      top: 95px;
      left: 20px;
      z-index: 50;
    }
      #search {
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 2;
      top: 20px;
      left: 74px;
    }

  </style> 

  <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.16/"></script>
  <script> 

    var map;
    require([
      "esri/map", "esri/dijit/BasemapGallery","esri/dijit/HomeButton","esri/dijit/Search",
       "esri/layers/ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer","esri/layers/FeatureLayer", "dojo/parser","esri/dijit/Attribution", 
       "dijit/form/ComboBox", "dojo/data/ItemFileReadStore", "dojo/_base/array", "dijit/registry", "esri/tasks/query",  
      "dijit/layout/BorderContainer", "dijit/layout/ContentPane", "dijit/TitlePane",
      "dojo/domReady!"
    ], function(
      Map, BasemapGallery,HomeButton,Search,ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer,FeatureLayer,
      parser,Attribution, ComboBox, ItemFileReadStore, array, registry,Query
    ) {

      parser.parse();

      map = new Map("map", {
        basemap: "topo",
         center: [77.2, 14],
         zoom: 7
      });

  var operationalLayer = new ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer("http://117.247.176.60:6080/arcgis/rest/services/BC_SH/BC_SH/MapServer");
   var school = new FeatureLayer("http://117.247.176.60:6080/arcgis/rest/services/BC_SH/BC_SH/MapServer/0", {  
     mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_SELECTION,  
   outFields: ["*"]  
  });  
  map.addLayers([operationalLayer,school]);

  var search = new Search({
                     map: map
                 }, "search");
                 search.startup();

  var home = new HomeButton({
        map: map
      }, "HomeButton");
      home.startup();

      //add the basemap gallery, in this case we'll display maps from ArcGIS.com including bing maps
      var basemapGallery = new BasemapGallery({
        showArcGISBasemaps: true,
        map: map
      }, "basemapGallery");
 basemapGallery.on('load',function(){
 basemapGallery.remove('basemap_0'); 
 basemapGallery.remove('basemap_1');    //remove unwanted base map from base map gallery
 basemapGallery.remove('basemap_2'); 
 basemapGallery.remove('basemap_3'); 
 basemapGallery.remove('basemap_4');
basemapGallery.remove('basemap_5'); 
 basemapGallery.remove('basemap_8'); 
}); 
      basemapGallery.startup();

      basemapGallery.on("error", function(msg) {
        console.log("basemap gallery error:  ", msg);
      });


         var populateList = function(results) {
            //Populate the ComboBox with unique values
            var zone;
            var values = [];
            var testVals = {};

            values.push({
                name: "ALL"
            })

            //Loop through the QueryTask results and populate an array
            //with the unique values
            var features = results.features;
            array.forEach(features, function(feature) {
                zone = feature.attributes.DistrictName;
                if (zone) {
                    if (!testVals[zone]) {
                        testVals[zone] = true;
                        values.push({
                            name: zone
                        });
                    }
                }
            });

            //Create a ItemFileReadStore and use it for the
            //ComboBox's data source
            var dataItems = {
                identifier: 'name',
                label: 'name',
                items: values
            };
            var store = new ItemFileReadStore({
                data: dataItems
            });
            registry.byId("mySelect").set('store', store);
        }

        queryTask = new esri.tasks.QueryTask("http://117.247.176.60:6080/arcgis/rest/services/BC_SH/BC_SH/MapServer/0");
        var query = new esri.tasks.Query();
        query.returnGeometry = false;
        query.outFields = ["DistrictName"];
        query.where = "DistrictName<> ''";
        queryTask.execute(query, populateList);

        app = {  
        zoomRow: function(id){   
        var districtname=id.toString();
        alert(districtname);
         // school.clearSelection();  
          var query = new Query();  
          query.where = "DistrictName='" + districtname + "'";  
           query.outFields = ["DistrictName"];
          query.returnGeometry = true;  
          school.selectFeatures(query, FeatureLayer.SELECTION_NEW, function (features) {  
            var Districtna = features[0].geometry;  
            var theExtent = Districtna.getExtent().expand(2); 
            map.setExtent(theExtent);  
          });  
        }  
      };  


});



  </script> 
</head> 

<body class="claro">
 <div id="search"></div> 
    <div id="map" 
         data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" 
         data-dojo-props="region:'center'" 
         style="padding:0;">

      <div style="position:absolute; right:10px; top:10px; z-Index:999;">
        <div data-dojo-type="dijit/TitlePane" 
             data-dojo-props="title:'Switch Basemap', closable:false, open:false">
          <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" style="width:200px; height:280px; overflow:auto;">
            <div id="basemapGallery"></div>
          </div>
        </div>


      </div>
     <div style="position:absolute; right:250px; top:10px; z-Index:999;" value="Select District" id="mySelect" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.ComboBox" onchange="app.zoomRow(document.getElementById('mySelect').value);"/>
        <div id="HomeButton"></div>

    </div>
</body> 

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got this error because you are trying to get an Extent of point geometry , so the Point geometry does not have an extent like (polyline,polygone ...)

the school feature layer is a `esriGeometryPoint` Layer , so you cant work with extents here :

I used the centerAndZoom map function to zoom to the returned point geometry , 
and  i've add graphic for better rendring and infotemplate when the  graphic is clicked .

here is a solution :

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
<head> 
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"/>
  <title></title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.16/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">    
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.16/esri/css/esri.css">
  <style> 
    html, body, #map {
      padding:0;
      margin:0;
      height:100%;
    }
    #HomeButton {
      position: absolute;
      top: 95px;
      left: 20px;
      z-index: 50;
    }
      #search {
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 2;
      top: 20px;
      left: 74px;
    }

  </style> 

  <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.16/"></script>
  <script> 

    var map;
    require([
      "esri/map", "esri/dijit/BasemapGallery","esri/dijit/HomeButton","esri/dijit/Search",
      "esri/layers/ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer","esri/layers/FeatureLayer", "dojo/parser","esri/dijit/Attribution", 
      "dijit/form/ComboBox", "dojo/data/ItemFileReadStore", "dojo/_base/array", "dijit/registry", "esri/tasks/query",  
      "esri/symbols/SimpleMarkerSymbol","esri/Color", "esri/InfoTemplate", "esri/graphic",
      "dijit/layout/BorderContainer", "dijit/layout/ContentPane", "dijit/TitlePane",

      "dojo/domReady!"
    ], function(
      Map, BasemapGallery,HomeButton,Search,ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer,FeatureLayer,
      parser,Attribution, ComboBox, ItemFileReadStore, array, registry,Query,
      SimpleMarkerSymbol,Color,InfoTemplate,Graphic
    ) {

      parser.parse();

      map = new Map("map", {
        basemap: "topo",
         center: [77.2, 14],
         zoom: 7
      });

  var operationalLayer = new ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer("http://117.247.176.60:6080/arcgis/rest/services/BC_SH/BC_SH/MapServer");
   var school = new FeatureLayer("http://117.247.176.60:6080/arcgis/rest/services/BC_SH/BC_SH/MapServer/0", {  
     mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_SELECTION,  
   outFields: ["*"]  
  });  
  map.addLayers([operationalLayer,school]);

  var search = new Search({
                     map: map
                 }, "search");
                 search.startup();

  var home = new HomeButton({
        map: map
      }, "HomeButton");
      home.startup();

      //add the basemap gallery, in this case we'll display maps from ArcGIS.com including bing maps
      var basemapGallery = new BasemapGallery({
        showArcGISBasemaps: true,
        map: map
      }, "basemapGallery");
 basemapGallery.on('load',function(){
 basemapGallery.remove('basemap_0'); 
 basemapGallery.remove('basemap_1');    //remove unwanted base map from base map gallery
 basemapGallery.remove('basemap_2'); 
 basemapGallery.remove('basemap_3'); 
 basemapGallery.remove('basemap_4');
basemapGallery.remove('basemap_5'); 
 basemapGallery.remove('basemap_8'); 
}); 
      basemapGallery.startup();

      basemapGallery.on("error", function(msg) {
        console.log("basemap gallery error:  ", msg);
      });


         var populateList = function(results) {
            //Populate the ComboBox with unique values
            var zone;
            var values = [];
            var testVals = {};

            values.push({
                name: "ALL"
            })

            //Loop through the QueryTask results and populate an array
            //with the unique values
            var features = results.features;
            array.forEach(features, function(feature) {
                zone = feature.attributes.DistrictName;
                if (zone) {
                    if (!testVals[zone]) {
                        testVals[zone] = true;
                        values.push({
                            name: zone
                        });
                    }
                }
            });

            //Create a ItemFileReadStore and use it for the
            //ComboBox's data source
            var dataItems = {
                identifier: 'name',
                label: 'name',
                items: values
            };
            var store = new ItemFileReadStore({
                data: dataItems
            });
            registry.byId("mySelect").set('store', store);
        }

        queryTask = new esri.tasks.QueryTask("http://117.247.176.60:6080/arcgis/rest/services/BC_SH/BC_SH/MapServer/0");
        var query = new esri.tasks.Query();
        query.returnGeometry = false;
        query.outFields = ["DistrictName"];
        query.where = "DistrictName<> ''";
        queryTask.execute(query, populateList);

        app = {  
        zoomRow: function(id){   
        var districtname=id.toString();
        alert(districtname);
         // school.clearSelection();  
          var query = new Query();  
          query.where = "DistrictName='" + districtname + "'";  
           query.outFields = ["DistrictName"];
          query.returnGeometry = true;  
          school.selectFeatures(query, FeatureLayer.SELECTION_NEW, function (features) {  
            var Districtna = features[0].geometry; 
            console.log(Districtna); 
            // adding graphic style
            var sms = new SimpleMarkerSymbol().setStyle(
            SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE_SQUARE).setColor(new Color([255,0,0,0.5]));
            // showing info on graphic click
            var infoTemplate = new InfoTemplate("Sample Text","District:"+features[0].DistrictName);
            var graphic = new Graphic(Districtna,sms,null,infoTemplate);
            map.graphics.clear();
            //adding graphic to map
            map.graphics.add(graphic);
            // get max map zoom
            maxZoom = map.getMaxZoom();  
            // center and zoom to point district
            map.centerAndZoom(Districtna,maxZoom-5);
          });  
        }  
      };  


});



  </script> 
</head> 

<body class="claro">
 <div id="search"></div> 
    <div id="map" 
         data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" 
         data-dojo-props="region:'center'" 
         style="padding:0;">

      <div style="position:absolute; right:10px; top:10px; z-Index:999;">
        <div data-dojo-type="dijit/TitlePane" 
             data-dojo-props="title:'Switch Basemap', closable:false, open:false">
          <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" style="width:200px; height:280px; overflow:auto;">
            <div id="basemapGallery"></div>
          </div>
        </div>


      </div>
     <div style="position:absolute; right:250px; top:10px; z-Index:999;" value="Select District" id="mySelect" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.ComboBox" onchange="app.zoomRow(document.getElementById('mySelect').value);"/>
        <div id="HomeButton"></div>

    </div>
</body> 

</html>
```

Comment: thank you its working fine.I have one more that can display total number of school for selected district

Comment: just use `features.length` ! but one more thing , you have a district layer but it does not contains all ditricts in your combo

Comment: no i have 30 district